# Firebase: Render list of posts created with .push in React component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `.push` to create an object in Firebase with a unique ID. I am trying to then display the object in a React component by updating the components state.

My component displays the data correctly when there is no unique key (when I manually create the entry in firebase as a direct child but not when creating via `.push`.

Here is my react component render statement:

```
    class Snapshots extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dealership: ' ',
      calls: '',
      chats: '',
      forms: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('snapshot');
    const callsRef = firebaseRef.child('calls');
    const chatsRef = firebaseRef.child('chats');
    const formsRef = firebaseRef.child('forms');

    callsRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        calls: snap.val()
      });
    });

    chatsRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        chats: snap.val()
      });
    });

    formsRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        forms: snap.val()
      });
    });
  }

    render() {
        return (<div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <table className="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Phone Calls</th>
                  <th>Live Chats</th>
                  <th>Web Forms</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td scope="row" className="phone-calls data-background"><span className="snapshot">{this.state.calls}</span></td>
                  <td className="live-chats data-background"><span className="snapshot">{this.state.chats}</span></td>
                  <td className="web-forms data-background"><span className="snapshot">{this.state.forms}</span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
http://screencast.com/t/spUuU5dDx

I'm missing some reference to the unique key when referencing state in my input fields but I don't know how to actually get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.push()` you get a unique key, like in their example:

```
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref('posts').push().key;
```

And then you cant set data like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/' + newPostKey).set({ someData: data });
```

Or like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/' + newPostKey).on('value', (data) => {
    // data.val()...
});
```

Comment: I realize it has been a while since your answer, but where is the best place to store that `newPostKey` variable? Suppose I had a list of `div`s containing data in the database, each with a checkbox next to them, and I wanted users to be able to select what data to delete. How can I link what checkbox is clicked to what data that represents in the database?